# DaVinci resolve could not find any openCL capable GPUs

Tags: video

just started video editing for my youtube channel and I chose to use DaVinci resolve for my video editing. I downloaded DaVinci 16 5 days ago and I have not been able to use it. Whenever  I open it, it display this dialog message "DaVinci resolve could not find any openCL capable GPUs..." I tried to look for solution all over the internet only to find none. I think the problem lies between Display properties, maybe display drivers and Graphics of my computer.
So my laptop runs with  Intel(R) HD Graphics  (Display adapters).
Trying to update the drivers does not bring any help as well,
What can I do to have my DaVinci running? Any help plz.

Comment: You need to give more informations about your current pc hardware.

Comment: Ok am currently using Toshiba satellite E205 with 4GB RAM and 500GB HD. Intel(R) HD Graphics (Display adapters), Intel(R)  Core(TM)ci 5  2.27GHz processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Intel Core i5-430M CPU has Ironlake HD Graphics which does not support OpenCL, see on [WikiChip](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/hd_graphics_(ironlake)). You need newer hardware if you want to use OpenCL acceleration.

Comment: having known my PC, what open  source video editing software can you recommend for me ? Thanks

Comment: Try VSDC, that is free and system requirements are very low: http://www.videosoftdev.com/